# Which server setup would be easiest to send a photo/text from an iOS app (swift) to a place where I can download/access them?

Tags: swift, server, client, photo

I'm using swift — and the app needs to send a photo and matching text (that a user submits) to a server so that I can download the photo/text.

Would an existing FTP server that I have setup for my website be possible for this application? Or would it make more sense to do something with a web portal?

During my research, I'm finding options like [Backendless](https://backendless.com/), [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire), [Gold Racoon](https://github.com/albertodebortoli/GoldRaccoon), and various others. They seem like overkill for the simple task I'm looking to accomplish. Is there some minimal service out there that can automate my simple need? If not, which of these options would you recommend for my situation?

Ideally the setup would be free, but I'd be willing to spend up to $100 or $10/month if the service fits.

I'm new to app development so I'm feeling overwhelmed with the options and not sure how to begin researching. I hope beginner questions aren't frowned upon here — I would really appreciate any advise on what I should begin learning to achieve my goal of sending a photo+text from an iOS app to a place where I can access them.

If there are other questions I should be asking to achieve this, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case there are two main routes to consider

**1. BYOS (Bring Your Own Server)**

With this option, you are responsible for creating and *maintenance* of your own server.

Now you can use various services such as [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) and [Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/) for this.

On top of this, you would be responsible for creating your own database and maintaining it as well. Plus, you would need to write server side code along with client side code (the app) in order to instantiate communication between the two.

The advantage of this is that you *virtually* have control of everything but I think it is pretty clear how painful this task is.

**2: BAS (Backend As a Service) *Highly recommended***

With this route, you simply have to write the app and let another service handle the server side of things. One of the most common ones is [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/). Most folks including startups go down this route.

There are a bunch of [other services out there](https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase%20alternatives&oq=firebae%20al&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.4375j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

**Two Cents:**

Whatever option or service you decide to use, I would recommend you make sure that:

a. The service has a good track record.

You do not want something that might end up getting shutdown in the next couple months. I know it is hard to predict this but certain initial guesses/probabilities can be made.

b. Make sure its community is vibrant.

The last thing you as a newbie wants is to be stuck and have no one to help you. Research around and see the different questions people ask and whether or not answers exist.